# Use of まだしも in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> 部活ならまだしも、サークルにまで顧問がいたら先生が何人いても足りない

the latter part is talking about how there aren't enough teachers for every circle to have an adviser, but the "rather; better" definition of まだしも doesn't make sense here.

It has already been established that clubs have more stature than circles for context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Xならまだしも means "If it were [only] X, that could be coped with, but [something more is involved]". As a translation, I'd suggest "X would be one thing, but Y on top . . ." How about: "If it were just the clubs, that would be one thing, but if advisers were extended to the circles as well, no matter how many teachers there were there wouldn't be enough"